# On what set is the group action of the sequence truncation function, the identity function?

Tags: group-theory, functions, set-theory, group-actions, ordinals

Let $\omega^\omega$ be the set of finite sequences of positive natural numbers and let $\lvert x\rvert$ be the ordinal of $x\in\omega^\omega$ given by using the terms as coefficents in Cantor normal form.

Let $f:\omega^\omega\to\omega^\omega$ be a surjection that truncates sequences, i.e. sends $\forall n:\omega^n\setminus\omega^{n-1}\to\omega^{n-1}$.  Then every sequence $f^n(x)$ under composition is eventually constant.

Clearly $\Bbb N$ has a monoidal action given by $F^{-n}(\emptyset):n\in\Bbb N$ over some set $X\to X$ which contains infinitely nested sequences of inclusions drawn from $\omega^\omega$, and which satisfies $\lvert F^{-1}(x)\rvert\geq\lvert x\rvert$.

It is my tentative belief that $F:\omega^n\mapsto\omega^{n-1}$ and therefore $F:\omega^\omega\to\omega^\omega$.

So there is an $f$-compatible monoid action, but it is my belief that there is also an $f$-compatible **group** action of $\Bbb Z$ given by $F^n(x):n\in\Bbb Z$  over sets $X$ which contain $\omega^\omega$ within their transitive closure.

Is this correct, and if so, on what set does it act?  I'm trying to do here is to better picture this group action.

I believe the fact that there exists $\emptyset\in\omega^\omega$ such that $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ means the only such group action of $\Bbb Z$ is an identity function on the trivial group.

Moreover, I think the only set on which $F$ can be the identity function, is $\mathcal P(\omega^\omega)$.  Is this correct?

If I elaborate slightly - let $F:\mathcal P(\omega^\omega)\to\mathcal P(\omega^\omega)$ be given by:

$F^{-1}(x)=\{y:f(y)\in x\}$

and consider the group action of $z\in\Bbb Z$ on $F^z$ where $z$ indicates function composition.

> On what set is $F$ the identity function?

i.e. what set $X$ satisfies $F(X)=X$?

Comment: There are many unclear or unnecessary statements. For instance, is $\omega^{\omega}$ the set of *finite* sequences of positive integers? Why do you write $F^{-1}(x)$? Where does $X$ lie in $F(X)=X$? In $\mathcal{P}(\omega^{\omega})$ or in $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\omega^{\omega}))$?

Comment: @nombre thank-you for taking time to ask for clarification. Yes, finite sequences - I've corrected the question. I write $F^{-1}$ because it then gives an $F$ that goes in the same direction as $f$. As for where $X$ lies in $F(X)=X$, I think it's in $\mathcal P(X)$ but this is part of what I'm unclear on.  I mention transitive closure later on. Perhaps this answers your question: Can $F$ only be well-defined on a set which is its own transitive closure? Truth is, I'm struggling to define families of supersets $S$ of $X$ on which some $F:S\to S$ which "models" $f$ has a group action.